# How to include error in input array when duing curve fit

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, curve-fitting, statsmodels

Comment: I'm typing most of the function here.

Suppose I have this data set

```
X                Y                Err
1.75000000e+00   1.35782019e+03   5.30513124e-01  
1.50000000e+00   1.35253305e+03   5.30038166e-01
1.25000000e+00   1.34828730e+03   3.74007356e-01
1.00000000e+00   1.34305172e+03   6.01032718e-01
7.50000000e-01   1.33856734e+03   4.10658016e-01
5.00000000e-01   1.33354481e+03   3.75859437e-01
2.50000000e-01   1.32768190e+03   6.87483944e-01
0.00000000e+00   1.32243488e+03   1.01751280e+00
```

I can carry fits in several ways on it (using python). `polyfit(X,Y,1)` returns only the slope and intercept without error estimate. `scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear_func,X,Y)` returns

```
(array([   20.03165298,  1322.9624529 ]), array([[ 0.08707502, -0.07619064],
   [-0.07619064,  0.09523831]]))
```

where `linear_func(X,a,b)` returns `(a*X+b)` this mean that the error both in the `slope` and `intercept` is 0.09 which is too low considering the error I have in the measurement. I including the error as weights (which is the only way I found to include the error), `scipy.optimze.curve_fit(linear_func,X,Y,simae=1/E)` yield

```
(array([   20.30379913,  1322.49139001]), array([[ 0.02571288, -0.00776912],
   [-0.00776912,  0.00959137]]))
```

The error here is even smaller. Searching around, I've found [`statsmodel`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/index.html) which, using [`OLS`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html) yield

```
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const       1322.9625      0.309   4286.883      0.000      1322.207  1323.718
x1            20.0317      0.295     67.884      0.000        19.310    20.754
```

which seams reasonable, if a little small.

Finally, using [`WLS`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS) results with

```
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const       1323.2200      0.337   3928.369      0.000      1322.396  1324.044
x1            19.8639      0.314     63.234      0.000        19.095    20.633
```

Which is about the same.

So, my question is, what is the difference between the two methods (I assume that `OLS` and `WLS` are the same as weighted errors on `curve_fit`)? Is there a way to manually estimate the errors in the fitting parameters?

Comment: terminology question: are the `Err` variance or standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

OLS and curve_fit without weights assume that the variance of the error in the fit is the same for each observation.

`curve_fit` and `WLS` assume that the variance of your error is **proportional** to your inverse weights. The absolute level of the weights that you specify does not affect the standard errors of the parameters, only the relative magnitudes are relevant.

scipy's curve_fit just obtained an additional option `absolute_sigma=False` that if true uses the inverse of the weights as absolute instead of relative magnitude.

From the question it's not clear to me that this is the relevant answer.

The model in the linear is assumed to be `y = X * beta + u`
where u are the errors that are assumed to be independent from each other but with varying variance `sig2_u / weights`.

`sig2_u` is the overall variance estimated from the actual residuals or estimation errors.

`absolute_sigma=True` means that we set `sig2_u` equal to 1 and don't estimate it from the fitted regression.

Answer (score 0):

Yotam, you wrote

```
scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear_func,X,Y) returns

(array([   20.03165298,  1322.9624529 ]), array([[ 0.08707502, -0.07619064],
   [-0.07619064,  0.09523831]]))

where linear_func(X,a,b) returns (a*X+b) this mean that the error both in 
the slope and intercept is 0.09 which is too low considering the error I 
have in the measurement.
```

That's not correct.  The second component returned by curve_fit() is the covariance matrix, so the estimated uncertainties would be sqrt(0.087075) and sqrt(0.0952383), so roughly 0.3, which is closer to the right scale, especially given that these would be 1-sigma values, not 3-sigma values.

The other comments about what the weights mean and using the absolute_sigma also apply.